# Multiple roscores synchronize

Tags: ros, multiple, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If we have a group of rosnodes with a master core and another group of nodes with another roscore... If these set of rosnodes want to communicate with each other, will the different roscore time sync between them? If so, how?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197382/multiple-roscores-synchronize/) by [jennifer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2259/jennifer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2014-11-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jennifer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2259/jennifer/) on 2014-11-13**:
Thanks a lot.. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can try the packages [FKIE](http://wiki.ros.org/multimaster_fkie) or [ROCON](http://wiki.ros.org/rocon_multimaster).

---

Originally posted by [Jbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1000/jbot/) with karma: 429 on 2014-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been using [multimaster_fkie](http://wiki.ros.org/multimaster_fkie) for awhile now and it works very well with my setup.

You do not necessarily need to have the machines synchronised in time, but the result will be messages published with out-of-sync timestamps.

You should ensure the machines are synchronised in time, particularly if you are using TF.

---

Originally posted by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) with karma: 806 on 2014-11-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kensley](https://answers.ros.org/users/20854/kensley/) on 2014-11-18**:
Can you provide and information on your use case or setup? My team is just starting to look at FKIE for multimaster. Any information would be appreciated. Thanks

**Comment by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) on 2014-11-19**:
You need to run 2 nodes on each machine: `master_discovery` from package `master_discovery_fkie`, and `master_sync` from package `master_sync_fkie`. I created a launch file. Also, there is a GUI you can load by running the node `node_manager` from package `node_manager_fkie`. It's that simple!